# How to substring and join with another table with the substring result

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have 2 tables: errorlookup and errors.
errorlookup has 2 columns: codes and description.
The codes are of length 2.
errors has 2 columns id and errorcodes.
The errorcodes are of length 40 meaning they code store 20 error codes for each id.
I need to display all the description associated with the id by substring the errorcodes and matching with code in errorlookup table.
Sample data for errorlookup:

```
codes:description
   12:Invalid
   22:Inactive
   21:active
```

Sample data for errors:

```
id:errorcodes
 1:1221
 2:2112
 3:1222
```

I cant use LIKE as it would result in too many errors. I want the errorcodes column to be broken down into strings of length 2 and then joined with the errorlookup.
How can it be done?

Comment: Is redesigning the tables an option?  There's probably a better way than storing 20 integers as a concatenated string.

Comment: I realize this may be out of your control, but this is the problem you run into when you combine multiple pieces of data within a single column.  had this design defect not been made, it would have been stored as separate rows and an easy "standard" join would solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you really cannot alter the tables structure, here's another approach:

Create an auxilary `numbers` table:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers
( i INT NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (i)
) ;

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES
( 1 ) ;   
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES
( 2 ) ;
--- ...
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES
( 100 ) ;
```

Then you could use this:

```
SELECT err.id
     , err.errorcodes
     , num.i
     , look.codes
    , look.descriptionid
FROM
    ( SELECT i, 2*i-1 AS pos      --- odd numbers
      FROM numbers
      WHERE i <= 20               --- 20 pairs
    ) num 
  CROSS JOIN 
    errors  err
  JOIN 
    errorlookup  look
      ON look.codes = SUBSTR(err.errorcodes, pos, 2)
ORDER BY 
    err.errorcodes
  , num.i ;
```

Test at: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7939/18)

```
ID  ERRORCODES  I   CODES  DESCRIPTIONID
1   1221        1   12     Invalid
1   1221        2   21     Active
3   1222        1   12     Invalid
3   1222        2   22     Inactive
2   2112        1   21     Active
2   2112        2   12     Invalid
```

Comment: +1 I found another good example of the use of cross joins [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2005/09/12/7755.aspx).  The question is tagged "oracle"; what happens in oracle if `CROSS JOIN errors...` is replaced with `JOIN errors...`?  In MySQL you still get the cartesian product.

Comment: MySQL treats `CROSS JOIN` and `JOIN` as equivalent. It allows `a JOIN b` (without `ON` condition). It also allows `a CROSS JOIN b ON b.columnX = a.columnX`. Both are not valid ANSI/ISO SQL syntax. Oracle will produce an error with those.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest solution is to "normalize" your errocodes table using a PL/SQL function. That way you can keep the current (broken) table design, but still access its content as if it was properly normlized.

```
create type error_code_type as object (id integer, code varchar(2))
/

create or replace type error_table as table of error_code_type
/

create or replace function unnest_errors
   return error_table pipelined
is  
  codes_l integer;
  i       integer;
  one_row error_code_type := error_code_type(null, null);
begin
  for err_rec in (select id, errorcodes from errors) loop
    codes_l := length(err_rec.errorcodes);
    i := 1;
    while i < codes_l loop
        one_row.id   := err_rec.id;
        one_row.code := substr(err_rec.errorcodes, i, 2);
        pipe row (one_row);
        i := i + 2;
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

Now with this function you can do something like this:

```
select er.id, er.code, el.description
from table(unnest_errors) er
  join errorlookup el on el.codes = er.code;
```

You can also create a view based on the function to make the statements a bit easier to read:

```
create or replace view normalized_errorcodes 
as
select *
from table(unnest_errors);
```

Then you can simply reference the view in the real statement.

(I tested this on 11.2 but I believe it should work on 10.x as well)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with `LIKE`.  MySQL has an `RLIKE` function that allows matching by regular expression (I don't know if it's present in Oracle.)  You could use `errorlookup.code` as a pattern to match against `errors.errorcodes`.  The `(..)*` pattern is used to prevent things like "1213" from matching, for example, "21".

```
SELECT *
FROM error
JOIN errorlookup
WHERE errorcodes RLIKE CONCAT('^(..)*',code)
ORDER BY id;

+------+----------+------+
| id   | errorcode| code |
+------+----------+------+
|    1 | 11       | 11   |
|    2 | 1121     | 11   |
|    2 | 1121     | 21   |
|    3 | 21313245 | 21   |
|    3 | 21313245 | 31   |
|    3 | 21313245 | 32   |
|    4 | 21       | 21   |
+------+----------+------+
```